# Knight Tour Heuristic

Tags: c++, programming-challenge

God sidetracked by this question: [“Rock-Paper-Scissors Tournament”](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/241362/507)

Which led me to the ["Knight's Tour" problem](https://open.kattis.com/problems/magicalmysteryknight).

Initially did a brute force solution. This worked for most of the test. But timed out for the last test. No matter how I added quick exits to the brute force solution could not pass the last test. So did some googling and implemented a heuristic solution on the "Diamond" Square partial solution (Dr. Roget in 1840 who extended it from Euler’s).

The full code is [here](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/Kattis/tree/master/KnightTour)

### SquareDiamond.h

```
#ifndef THORSANVIL_CONTEST_KNIGHTTOUR_SQUAREDIAMOND_H
#define THORSANVIL_CONTEST_KNIGHTTOUR_SQUAREDIAMOND_H

/*
 * This is a heuristic to solve the knight tour.
 * As such it does not always work.
 *
 * If the problem space already has a lot of squares already defined.
 * it is likely to fall outside the scope of the heuristics and cause it
 * to fail quickly.
 *
 * If the problem space is sparse then this algorithm works very well,
 * though not perfectly (as the defined points must fall inside the
 * diamond square patter perfectly).
 *
 * We are using a symmetric already solved version
 * of the knights tour as developed by Dr Roget in 1840.
 *
 * In this solution the board is divided into 4 quarters
 * Each quarter has four routes (each route covers 4 squares).
 * See sd.gif included with this project.
 *
 * So we now have 16 routes (4 routes per quarter). Each can be run forward or backwards.
 *
 * So given a starting point, we run the route forward then backward.
 * At the end we work out what other routes can be reached (A maximum of 7 other routes
 * you can not jump back to the same route all other poisition in the current route
 * will have been used).
 *
 * So this effectively this reduces the problem to 16 vertices.
 * Each vertices is connected to 7 other vertices.
 */

#include <vector>

namespace ThorsAnvil::Contest::KnightTour
{

class Board;
class SquareDiamond
{
    private:
        // Possible moves a knight can move.
        static std::pair<int, int> constexpr pos[8] = {{-1, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, -1}, {1, -2}, {-1, -2}, {-2, -1}, {-2, 1}};

        // The 16 routes.
        // The chessboard is numbered 1-64.
        // Bottom left is 1.
        // Numbers increase by 1 left to right.
        // Numbers increase by 8 bottom to top.
        static int constexpr cells[17][4] = {
            {-1, -1, -1, -1},   // row 0 is invalid and used as spacing.
                                // We index from 1 to make things more logical.
            { 1, 11, 28, 18},
            { 2, 12, 27, 17},
            { 3, 20, 26,  9},
            { 4, 19, 25, 10},
            { 5, 15, 32, 22},
            { 6, 16, 31, 21},
            { 7, 24, 30, 13},
            { 8, 23, 29, 14},
            {33, 43, 60, 50},
            {34, 44, 59, 49},
            {35, 52, 58, 41},
            {36, 51, 57, 42},
            {37, 47, 64, 54},
            {38, 48, 63, 53},
            {39, 56, 62, 45},
            {40, 55, 61, 46}
        };

        // Map from a chess square to a route.
        static int constexpr squreToCellData[65] = {
            -1,
             1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,
             3,  4,  1,  2,  7,  8,  5,  6,
             2,  1,  4,  3,  6,  5,  8,  7,
             4,  3,  2,  1,  8,  7,  6,  5,
             9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
            11, 12,  9, 10, 15, 16, 13, 14,
            10,  9, 12, 11, 14, 13, 16, 15,
            12, 11, 10,  9, 16, 15, 14, 13
        };

        Board&  board;
        using CellRoute     = std::vector<int>;
        using CellRoutePair = std::pair<CellRoute, CellRoute>;

        CellRoutePair getRoute(int square);

        bool runTour(int currentMove, std::vector<int> const& route, int routePos, int x, int y);
        bool runTour(int currentMove, int x, int y);
        bool runTour(int currentMove);
    public:
        SquareDiamond(Board& board)
            : board(board)
        {}
        bool runTour(int x, int y)        {return runTour(1, x, y);}
};

}

#endif
```

### SquareDiamond.cpp

```
#include "squarediamond.h"
#include "board.h"

#include <algorithm>


using namespace ThorsAnvil::Contest::KnightTour;

// Given a square
// Find the route and calculate the path forward and backwards.
SquareDiamond::CellRoutePair SquareDiamond::getRoute(int square)
{
    int         cell    = squreToCellData[square];
    int const*  cellPtr = cells[cell];

    auto find   = std::find(cellPtr, cellPtr + 4, square);
    auto offset = find - cellPtr;

    std::vector<int>    r1(4);
    std::vector<int>    r2(4);

    for(int loop = 0; loop < 4; ++loop) {
        r1[loop] = cellPtr[(4 + offset + loop) % 4];
        r2[loop] = cellPtr[(4 + offset - loop) % 4];
    }

    return std::make_pair(r1, r2);
}


bool SquareDiamond::runTour(int currentMove, std::vector<int> const& route, int routePos, int x, int y)
{
    // Make sure the move is basically valid.
    if (!board.validMove(currentMove, x, y)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Update the board.
    Board::BoardUpdate   update(board, currentMove, x, y);
    if (!update) {
        // If this is not a semi-magic board then exit immediately.
        return false;
    }

    if (routePos != 4)
    {
        // We are not at the end of a route
        // So go to the next square in the root.
        int next = route[routePos];
        int newX = (next - 1) % 8;
        int newY = (next - 1) / 8;
        if(runTour(currentMove + 1, route, routePos + 1, newX, newY)) {
            update.setOk();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // We are at the end of a route.
    // So try and find the next route to run
    for(auto const& p: pos) {
        int newX = x + std::get<0>(p);
        int newY = y + std::get<1>(p);

        if (newX < 0 || newX >= 8 || newY < 0 || newY >= 8) {
            continue;
        }

        if (runTour(currentMove + 1, newX, newY)) {
            update.setOk();
            return true;
        }
    }
    // If no other routes work just returned to false.
    return false;
}

bool SquareDiamond::runTour(int currentMove, int x, int y)
{
    if (currentMove == 65) {
        return true;
    }

    int square = y * 8 + x + 1;
    CellRoutePair routes = getRoute(square);

    return runTour(currentMove, std::get<0>(routes), 1, x, y) || runTour(currentMove, std::get<1>(routes), 1, x, y);
}
```